# How to code Audio in app?

Tags: android, audio

**Some Background**

The app that i have made, is an interval app. This allows the user to choose the amount of time for each of the two intervals. When run, the app runs a countdown timer with the two user chosen time settings. I have two songs that i want to play for each interval, but i cant set the specific times when the song changes, because the user changes that. So if the user only picks 4 seconds for the first interval, I need the song to play for only that time, and when the countdown starts over with the other interval, I need the other song to play.

**Now to my real question.**

How do i call the audio to play? Ive looked at many questions, but they all say that i need to put the audioplayer in a new activity? If I put it in a new activity, will it not stop the countdown timer? How can i make it so that the countdown timer continues to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two methods to play sounds in android, one is SoundBoard (designed for short clips, don't use this if you want to play a song), the other one is MediaPlayer. You can play the audio by putting the file in the raw folder and then doing the following:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(ClassName.this, R.raw.sound); 
mp.start();
```

Then when the timer ends you can stop the song with `mp.stop();` and you can play the following audio file by doing:

```
mp.reset();  
mp = MediaPlayer.create(ClassName.this, R.raw.sound2);
```

When you finished remember to release the Mediaplayer with `mp.release();`.

I hope I understood what you need to do, you should also put the mediaplayer inside a new thread, see this from the official android developers documentation:

> To avoid hanging your UI thread, spawn another thread to prepare the
>   MediaPlayer and notify the main thread when done. However, while you
>   could write the threading logic yourself, this pattern is so common
>   when using MediaPlayer that the framework supplies a convenient way to
>   accomplish this task by using the prepareAsync() method. This method
>   starts preparing the media in the background and returns immediately.
>   When the media is done preparing, the onPrepared() method of the
>   MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, configured through
>   setOnPreparedListener() is called.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. Is there any way to allow the user to chooses which song he/she wants to play, from their own phones library of songs?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. You just need to get the path to the file, see this example for playing an external file: http://android-er.blogspot.it/2010/07/play-mp3-in-sd-card-using-androids.html, check also [this](http://android-er.blogspot.it/2010/01/implement-simple-file-explorer-in.html) for a file explorer.